# How to select only date with JXDatepicker

Tags: java

When I select date in SQL it is returned as:

```
Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018
```

But I need only the Date part, that is `Jan 31 2018`. How can I do this?

Comment: Off hand...Parse the string from JXDatePicker: `String[] dateParts = dateString.split("\\s+"); String newDateString = dateParts[1] + " " + dateParts[2] + " " + dateParts[5];`. See also this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999506/convert-string-date-to-string-date-different-format)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a reason to use **`org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker`** but rather of using **`JXDatePicker`**, I will simply show **[GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)** parsing using **`java.util.Date`**.

Try this source code:

```
System.out.println(new Date());
//will show your Date along with your local TimeZone
//result for me is : Sat Jan 13 08:47:59 IST 2018

//First changing local pacific time zone to GMT+01 level explicitly,
//otherwise it will show results as your local time zone by default.
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+01"));

String existingDateValue = "Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018";
DateFormat gmtFormat = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
try {
    //try to parse and validate existing date
    Date validatedExistingDate = gmtFormat.parse(existingDateValue);
    System.out.println(validatedExistingDate);
    //parsed validated date : Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018

    DateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
    System.out.println(newFormat.format(validatedExistingDate));
    //required Date is in GMT format : Jan 31, 2018
} catch (ParseException pex) {
    pex.printStackTrace();
}  finally {
    System.out.println("Current TimeZone : " + new Date());
    //now, reverting to my local TimeZone
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    System.out.println("Current TimeZone : " + new Date());
}
```